# Adding wordpress blog to rails app didn't work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

I am building a rails app and a wordpress blog under the same domain but each one is in a separate server. The rails app should be accessed by `mysite.com` and the blog by `mysite.com/blog` I read many documentations on the internet but none of them worked except for one which is so close but it had some issues.

I added to the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

These lines

```
upstream myBlogVPS {
        server *wordpress.blog.ip.adress*;  #fix me to point to your blog VPS
}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location /blog {
        proxy_pass         http://myBlogVPS;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    } .....}
```

The proxy returns me to a 404 page in my blog!! I tried to do so `proxy_pass    http://myBlogVPS/;` adding '/' after the the domain.

It worked proxying me to the blog's home page. However I am not able to access any other blog link from the rails app domain. like `mysite.com/blog/categories`. It always redirects me to the rails app home page `mysite.com`

To sum up, I want `mywebsite.com/blog` fully substitute the ip address of the blog in every single link in the blog.

Comment: In your WordPress blog, what have you set WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to?

Comment: I didn't change them what should I do?

Comment: The blog needs to know that it lives at `mywebsite.com/blog` now. These settings are either made in the general settings menu or the `wp-config.php` file (whichever you normally use).

Comment: I know that. but before doing so I want to make sure that it works manually. I have tried mysite.com/blog/wp-admin and It never works.

Comment: Ok, try `location /blog/ { proxy_pass http://myBlogVPS/; ... }` to map URI `/blog` to upstream `/`. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.